# Acesso a objetos de uma classe

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, objetos

```
class human(object):
    kind = 'humam'
    def __init__(self,name, sex, age):
        self.name = name
        self.sex = sex
        self.age = age
    def report(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(self.sex)
        print(self.age)
com = int(input('What would you like to do: \n 1) Add a contact \n 2) Info on a contact \n 3) Break\n'))
while com != 3:
    if com == 1:
        name,sex,age = input('Enter name sex age: ').split()
        name = human(name,sex,age)
    if com == 2:
        name = input('Enter name: ')
        name.report()
    com = int(input('What would you like to do: \n 1) Add a contact \n 2) Info on a contact \n 3) Break\n'))
```

Após definir alguns objetos de human, não consegui acessá-los se não for durante a mesma execução, por exemplo,selecionando 1 pra adicionar contato,uma vez instanciado john = human('john','male','20') quando selecionado 2 para verificar as informações do objeto aparece o seguinte erro:
    name.report()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'report'
Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Na verdade, a instância não fica com o nome `john`, mas sim `name`. O que você está fazendo é armazenando apenas um objeto `human` em uma variável `name` quando a opção é 1, mas quando é 2, você armazena o nome da pessoa em `name`, fazendo que perca a referência ao objeto, passando a ser uma *string*.

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando usar o método `report` em algo que não é um objeto da classe human. Na verdade dentro do seu `if com == 2`, você escreve que name é igual a um input. Ou seja, você está chamando o método `report` para uma string, e strings não têm método `report`. Explica melhor o que você quer fazer com esse código que talvez dê para te ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Quando constrói um `human` guarda-o numa variável chamada `name`

```
if com == 1:
    ...
    name = human(name,sex,age) #aqui o novo human é guardado em name
```

O problema começa logo no nome da variável, que deveria ser intuitivo para o seu conteúdo. Se ela guarda um `human` não se deveria chamar `name` pois isso induz em erro, e representa parte do problema que tem.

Mais abaixo este `name` recebe uma string:

```
if com == 2:
    name = input('Enter name: ') #aqui guarda a string por cima do human que tinha
```

Assim `name` passou a ter uma string e não um `human`, logo quando a seguir tenta chamar o método `report`:

```
 name.report()
```

Este falha pois não já não refere um `human`.

**Corrigindo e melhorando**

Pelo que vejo do seu programa está a tentar obter informações de pessoas já registadas. Para fazer isso é necessário que vá guardando cada pessoa numa lista:

```
humans = [] #lista para todos os humans registados
```

Depois quando adiciona uma nova pessoa, acrescenta-a à lista utilizando a função `append`. Para mostrar uma pessoa tem de percorrer a lista e se o nome inserido coincidir com o de algum elemento lista, mostra esse elemento com o método `report`:

```
while com != 3:
    if com == 1:
        name,sex,age = input('Enter name sex age: ').split()
        humans.append(human(name,sex,age)) #adiciona o novo human a lista
    if com == 2:
        name = input('Enter name: ')
        for somehuman in humans: #percorrer todos os humans
            if name in somehuman.name: #se o nome recebido está no nome do human
                somehuman.report() #chama o report nesse human
    com = int(input('What would you like to do: \n 1) Add a contact \n 2) Info on a contact \n 3) Break\n'))
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/siSLXA)